# How to calculate efficiently the index of an array, where the cumulative sum exceeded a threshold in Scala - Spark?

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, binary-search

Suppose we have an array of integers, of 100 elements.

`val a = Array(312, 102, 95, 255, ...)`

I want to find the index (say `k`) of the array where the cumulative sum of the first `k+1` elements is greater than a certain threshold, but for the first `k` element is less.

Because of the high number of elements in the array, I estimated a lower and upper index where in the between the `k` index should be:

`k_Lower <= k <= k_upper`

My question is, what is the best way to find this `k` index?

I tried it with a `while loop` when `k_lower = 30; k_upper = 47` and the `threshold = 20000`

```
var sum = 0
var k = 30
while (k <= 47 && sum <= 20000) {
  sum = test.take(k).sum
  k += 1
}

print(k-2)
```

I obtained the right answer, but I'm pretty sure that there is a more efficient or "Scala-ish" solution for this and I'm really new in Scala. Also I have to implement this in Spark.

Another question:
To optimize the method of finding the `k` index, I thought of using binary search, where the `min` and `max` values are `k_lower`, respective `k_upper`. But my attempt to implement this was unsuccessful. How should I do this?

I am using Scala 2.10.6 and Spark 1.6.0

**Update!**

I thought this approach is a good solution for my problem, but now I think, that I approached it wrongly. My actual problem is the following:

I have a bunch of JSON-s, which are loaded into Spark as an RDD with

`val eachJson = sc.textFile("JSON_Folder/*.json")`

I want to split the data into several partitions based on their size. The concatenated JSON-s size should be under a threshold. My idea was to go through the RDD one by one, calculate the size of a JSON and add it to an accumulator. When the accumulator is greater than the threshold, then I remove the last JSON and I obtain a new RDD with all the JSON-s until that, and I do it again with the remaining JSON-s. I read about tail recursion which could be a solution for this, but I wasn't able to implement it, so I tried to solve it differently. I map-ed the sizes for each JSON, and I obtained and RDD[Int]. And I managed to get all the indexes of this array, where the cumulative sum exceeded the threshold:

```
def calcRDDSize(rdd: RDD[String]): Long = {
  rdd.map(_.getBytes("UTF-8").length.toLong)
    .reduce(_ + _) //add the sizes together
}

val jsonSize = eachJson.map(s => s.getBytes("UTF-8").length)
val threshold = 20000
val totalSize = calcRDDSize(eachJson)
val numberOfPartitions = totalSize/threshold

val splitIndexes = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[Int]
var i = 0
while (i < numberOfPartitions)
  {
    splitIndexes += jsonSize.collect().toStream.scanLeft(0){_ + _}.takeWhile(_ < (i+1)*threshold).length-1
    i = i + 1
  }
```

However, I don't like this solution, because in the while loop I go through several times on the Stream and this is not really efficient. And now I have the indexes where I have to split the RDD, but I don't know how to split is.

Comment: This is a linear scan through some of  your data. Spark is going to be a pretty bad match for this (you might be able to do someithing with mapPartitons but it's still likely to do much more work than  is needed). Why do you have to use Spark?

Comment: "Because of the high number of elements in the array, I estimated a lower and upper index where in the between the k index should be:". How does that help? You still need to sum all the elements below the lower index. And for the same reason, binary search doesn't help. There's no need to recaculate the sums for every index you try.

Comment: I have to use Spark, because it's a requirement. I thought this will optimize a little bit, because I wanted to calculate the sum for each index (I know it's a bad solution) but I didn't want to calculate the sum for let's say, first 2 or first 3 elements. But I agree with you, I should not calculate it for each index. Please note, that I updated the question description!

Comment: "I want to split the data into several partitions based on their size." Why? Spark generally does this for you.

Comment: So is your actual problem to partition the data such that the sum of some attribute (in this case `s.getByes("UTF-8").length`) of each element is less than a specific limit? And why do you need to do this? There may be a better way of achieving your actual objective.

Comment: Exactly, I want that my concatenated JSON-s have a size little bit less than a hdfs block size, in my case 128 mb. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would to this with `scanLeft` and further optimize this using a lazy collection

```
a
.toStream
.scanLeft(0){_ + _}
.tail
.zipWithIndex
.find{case(cumsum,i) => cumsum > limit}
```

Comment: Why do the `zipWIthIndex`? Just do `a.toStrean.scanLeft(0){_+_}..tail.takeWhile(_ < k).length` (the `.tail` is because there's an issue - in your code too - when k is < 0 - because the scanLeft puts a zero at the start)

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul thanks, I added `.tail`. I'm aware that `zipWithIndex` is not necessary when using `takeWhile`, but I think it's my solution is more "speaking"

Comment: I find it confusing. The index of any element except the last is not needed to why bother taking the time and space to add it. Note your solution produces an `Option`, not an index, too (and you need to consider what to do when the cumulative sum never exceeds `k`)